# Vue.js: using a data object's method in inline event handler

Tags: vuejs2

I have a Vue(2.5+) component where I'm setting a data property to a new `Foo` object. Using `foo.bar()` in the click handler calls the method correctly, but throws `Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property 'someVariable' of null` when trying to modify properties inside the `Foo` class. Setting it up so that `Foo` is an object literal instead of a class also does not resolve the error.

I suspect something weird is happening with `this`, between the component and the class?

#### Vue component

```
import Foo from './foo.js'
export default {
    template: `<div @click="foo.bar"></div>`,
    data() {
        return {
            foo: new Foo()
        }
    },
    created() {
        console.log(foo); // foo is not null here
    }
}
```

#### Foo class

```
export default class Foo
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.someVariable = 0;
    }

    bar(e)
    {
        // modify this.someVariable
    }
}
```

but if I change the vue component to reference the external method through it's own "methods" property, it works.

#### Vue component (working)

```
import Foo from './foo.js'
export default {
    template: `<div @click="bar"></div>`,
    data() {
        return {
            foo: new Foo()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        bar(e) {
            this.foo.bar(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `foo.bar` is a function without any context attached to it, either `bind` the context or delegate as shown in your question

Comment: Wouldn't the context be the component?

Comment: Here what you intended to do was `foo.bar.bind(foo)`.

Comment: Thank you. Will you please elaborate why this must be done and explain more of the context? If you post in the form of an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, `foo.bar` without any context attached to it :

In JS functions are objects, just like any object they have their own `this` "pointer".
In the evaluation of their body, `this` is bound to a specific object referred to as `context` which is either the default context (automatically set) or user defined (manually set).

Inheritance in JS is achieved through a [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and methods ***should*** be defined on/attached to the class's prototype. Because of this, when you call `foo.bar()` :

- You are in a method call context, therefore `foo` will be bound to the method
- `bar` is searched on the object first then in the prototype chain

But methods behave just like any other property : when you do `foo.bar` you get a reference to the actual method which is an *unbound function* (default behavior for methods, since it is bound when called on an object).

Therefore, what you really need to do in this situation is `foo.bar.bind(foo)`.

I would also suggest taking a quick look into [this ES6 proposal for a bind operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) and its implementation as a [Babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-function-bind) which allows nice things like passing `::foo.bar` instead of `foo.bar.bind(foo)`